# SendEmail function in google sheet with customized subject

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set a Send Email command Button in google sheet which sends me an xlsx extension file with a common subject as " Google Sheet to Excel". I want to use Cell A2 & B6 as the subject.

Can anyone please help me to rewrite the code? I know nothing about javascript.

```
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
    blob.setName(ss.getName() + ".xlsx");
    MailApp.sendEmail("nayeem.evan@gmail.com", "Google Sheet to Excel", "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});
  } catch (f) {
  Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

I want to replace the Google Sheet to Excel to Cell Ref "A2 & C6"

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("nayeem.evan@gmail.com",((ss.getSheetByName("nameofsheet").getRange("A2").getValue()) + " " + (ss.getSheetByName("nameofsheet").getRange("B6").getValue())), "The XLSX file is attached", {attachments: [blob]});
```

Replace the name of the sheet to the actual sheet name on which values are stored in A2 and B6 cells. I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. It worked like a magic :)